# Translucent subviews of NSTableView flash when adding/inserting rows

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, nsoutlineview

I have a view based NSOutlineView in which the rows contains subviews which have an alpha value of less than 1.

When new rows are inserted or deleted (when the user expands or collapses a row) all of these sub views flash as they seem to temporarily be redrawn with an alpha value of 1.

Does anyone know how to stop this phenomenon ?

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking at this problem four hours, and as so often happens as soon as I post the question here I work out the answer for myself.

Setting up the translucent layers like this solve the issue:

```
- (void)setup {

    // This stops the strange flashing effect when collapsing/expanding rows

    self.wantsLayer = YES;
    [self.layer setShouldRasterize:YES];
}

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}
```